# How to update entry in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant figure it out. I have this variable (for example):

```
$level_building = "test,";
```

and this sql string:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE info_buildings SET building='$level_building' + building WHERE nick='$nick'") or die(mysql_error());
```

all i want to do is to add new text `test,` after existing text, but after updating it, sql shows 0 (`building=0`).. My sql output should look like this `test,test,test,`... Example: `building=test,test,test,` and each time i use sql string `UPDATE` it should write new `test` text in the same `building` string.. Sorry for bad english i hope you understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `+` is for arithmetic addition. To concatenate strings, use `CONCAT()`:

```
UPDATE info_buildings 
SET building = CONCAT('$level_building', building)
WHERE nick = '$nick'
```

All the MySQL string functions can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).

However, I recommend you reconsider your table design. Putting comma-separated lists in a single column is usually poor design. You should use a separate table with a row for each value.